# How filterdispatcher in struts2 locate the actiion class?

Tags: struts2

**my jsp：**

```
<form action="/we/login.action">
        <input type="text" name="STUNO"> <input type="submit"
            value="submit">
</form>
```

**my struts.xml:**

```
<struts>

</struts>
```

my src image description here

[image]

when I submit the form ,the server turn to creat loginAction.

I want to know why the filterdispatcher can find the class loginAction even
 I didn't config them in the struts.xml.

and it seems that the filterdispatcher can find the class LoginAction if I 
delete loginAction（l and L）

Comment: Filterdispatcher is using some sort of classloading utils.

Comment: Perhaps you are using the [convention plugin](https://struts.apache.org/docs/convention-plugin.html)? http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/struts/struts2-beginner-tutorial-with-convention-plugin-zero-configuration